# Tengo problemas cargando las fotos de la base de datos en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-4

*Me estaba funcionando correctamente pero de repente dejo de funcionar,cuando creo un producto guardo la foto en la carpeta Upload dentro de Storage, nose si habre cambiado algo sin darme cuenta y no alcanzo a ver el error,utilizo Laravel 7.3.0, alguien me puede ayudar:*

**AluminioController.php**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $productos = Aluminio::all();
        return view('aluminio.index',compact("productos"));
    }
public function store(Request $request){

        $productos = $request->all();

       
        if($request->hasFile('foto')){
           $productos['foto']=$request->file('foto')->store('uploads','public');
        }        
        Aluminio::create($productos);  
        
        
        session()->flash('exito','Producto creado correctamente');

        return redirect(route('aluminio.index'));
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
                  <div class="card-columns">
                    @foreach ($productos as $producto)
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                      
                    <div class="card m-4" style="width: 20rem">
                      <img src="{{ asset('storage').'/'.$producto->foto }}" class="card-img-top" width="200" alt="foto-producto">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">{{ $producto->tipologia}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ $producto->caracteristicas}}</p>
                        <a href="{{ route('aluminio.show', $producto->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">ver</a>
                        <a href="{{ route('aluminio.edit', $producto->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">editar</a>
                        <form action="{{ route('aluminio.destroy', $producto->id) }}" method="POST">                          
                          @csrf
                          @method('DELETE')
                          <button class="btn btn-primary mx-5 my-1"  type="submit">Eliminar</button>                                                 
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>   
                    </div>                     
                    @endforeach
                  </div>          
                </div>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('aluminio/productos', 'AluminioController@index')->name('aluminio.index');
Route::get('aluminio/productos/create', 'AluminioController@create')->name('aluminio.create');
```

Comment: al utilizar la funcion DD() en el metodo index me muestra que la fotos se guardo correctamente.. he incluso en mysql en la tabla me mustra correctamente la ruta, y cuando voy a la carpeta Storage esta la foto correctamente guardada

Comment: Prueba con Storage::url `<img src="{{ asset( Storage::url($producto->foto) ) }}" >`

Comment: hace lo mimso no muestra la foto

Comment: Y muestra algún error?

Comment: no ninguna solo muestra lo que tiene el metodo alt de la etiqueta img

Comment: para el que le pueda interesar tuve que volver a utilizar el comando php artisan storage:link no se porque se habia desconfigurado